# F1 addin help redirects to Lync

Tags: outlook, vsto, chm, office-addins

I have been working on an outlook add-in for the last couple of weeks and I have been looking around for a way to get rid of the “Press F1 for add-in Help” context that is displayed when the user points the mouse on the add-in.

Now, I know that it is not possible because Microsoft does that in order to prevent users that the add-in is actually a third part component and was not provided by Microsoft and they don’t assume any responsibility of the add-in misbehavior.

**My problem is:** When I press F1 I don’t get the general outlook Help menu, but it gives me the Lync Help Menu. And that doesn’t make any sense for my users.

Any help, hint of how to get the F1 button to display the general Outlook Menu, and/or explanation of why is it behaving as described above are much appreciated.
Thanks.

**EDIT 1:** Lync's help page only shows up in Outlook 2013, on Outlook 2010, F1 displays original Outlook Help Menu.

**EDIT 2:** I created a new project added a ribbon and a button, I did not make any modification or set any options and added a setup project to test it on Outlook 2013 and Lync still shows up, so I am guessing that I did not do anything wrong in my first project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are right. The Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that.

However, you may consider setting up a keyboard hook to override the default behavior in Outlook. See [Using shortcut keys to call a function in an Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vsod/using-shortcut-keys-to-call-a-function-in-an-office-add-in) for a sample code.

Comment: I would have voted up but my reputation doesn't allow it yet, but thanks!

I actually considered that option and went for an article I found on Code Project (Not sure if it is okay to add the link of the article here).
The solution I found on CP worked on Outlook 2010 but not 2013 (yet?).
Anyways, i'll see the link you sent me and let you know if it worked.
That being said, it doesn't answer my question. because worst case scenario is I can't have custom help, so be it, but having Lync's or any other specific product's help displayed instead of general help (or Outlook's) is really bad.

Comment: Lync is a Microsoft's product. They know more than external developers. Pay special attention to the fact that Lync shows the user's status in Outlook. We are just guests on the party.